# ListView SelectedItem not updating UI after ListView been cleared

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro on a Windows Store App.

I have a ListView which has a SelectedItem that works the first time I use it. However, when I clear the ListView and re-bind it to another Collection, the selected item no longer appears selected.

The selectedItem property is being set correctly, since I can hit the breakpoint, and everything works has expected, just the View is not being updated with the selected item, after I clear the collection.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Edit:

View Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="DetailNotes"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DetailNotes}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailNote}"                                  
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Notes600ItemTemplate}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          caliburn:Message.Attach="[Event ItemClick] = [DetailNoteSelected($eventArgs)]"/>
```

ViewModel Code:

```
(...)
private Note selectedDetailNote;

public Note SelectedDetailNote
{
    get { return this.selectedDetailNote; }
    set 
    { 
        this.selectedDetailNote = value; 
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedDetailNote); 
    }
}

(...)

public void DetailNoteSelected(ItemClickEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Note n = (Note)eventArgs.ClickedItem;
    this.SelectedDetailNote = n;
}
```

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: Yes, I can. Already updated the question.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the problem was something related with me being clearing the collection, but the problem was only me using some explicit binding. After I removed that, everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! The problem was my explicit binding. I just left Caliburn do his work, and now it works!
Solution below:

View Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="DetailNotes"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Notes600ItemTemplate}"/>
```

ViewModel Code:

```
private Note selectedDetailNote;

public Note SelectedDetailNote
{
    get { return this.selectedDetailNote; }
    set 
    { 
        this.selectedDetailNote = value; 
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedDetailNote); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late, but your problem was binding mode. You should set it to TwoWay:

```
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailNote, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

In WinRT XAML default is OneWay.